# Best Way to Get a backpack Expander in TF2

Tags: team-fortress-2

My backpack is constantly filling up. This requires me to turn items into scrap that I wanted to save or even throw items away. I researched online and found that there is a Team Fortress 2 item called the backpack expander which increases the capacity of your backpack. That is great, but I cannot find out where to get it except for the Mann Co. Store. I would rather not pay for it, but whenever I join a trade server or pub I cannot find anyone who has it.

Does anyone know how to craft this item? I'm afraid the answer might be that it is un-craftable. If that is the case, does anyone have a good strategy on how to join a trade server that is likely to have the item you are looking for?

Open to other suggestions as well for locating and obtaining specific items.

Comment: Isn't it $0.99 for 100 slots (2 full pages)? What's the big deal with spending $1 from your steam wallet?

Comment: @skovacs1 Never setup a steam wallet, and I don't plan to. So in the world of steam "I'm BROKE!"

Comment: There is no recipe so I'm fairly sure it's not craftable. I believe the price I saw last on the trade markets put expanders at 2-2.5 ref, if that helps, but I've seen the price fluctuate as high as 8.5 ref so it depends on luck and timing.

Comment: If you have joined during the Christmas event in TF2, you _will_ get an (untradeable) backpack expander for free, alongside with some other gifts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, according to your comments, you are not willing to buy it.

> The backpack expander is a ungiftable and uncraftable. It is only available through purchase or trade.

The only possible way to get the backpack expander is through trade. I'm afraid you will likely have to purchase one through the steam wallet.

---

## *There is hope!!*

You may be able to find something one of the trading sites of team fortress 2:

- [dispenser](http://dispenser.tf/)
- [warehouse](http://www.tf2wh.com/)
- [backpack](http://backpack.tf/)

**Source**: [TF2 wiki](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Backpack_Expander)

Comment: when I said steam-"broke" I only meant I didn't want to spend any money. I do have a premium tf2 account so can trade items normally in that game.

Comment: @OrwellHindenberg Great!! then check out dispenser.tf! I just looked and there are lot's of people selling expanders for about 3 ref's

Comment: that site looks good. I will attempt to use it when I get home and revisit this question afterwards based on my results.

Comment: @OrwellHindenberg did this ever end up working for you?

Comment: Yes this worked!

Answer (score 1):

I bought my Backpack expander yesterday for $0.99 its a big help i don't need to delete or craft every time my backpack is full and it gives me a free Mann. Co. Cap... If you don't have credit card visa or Paypal like me you can buy steam card or steam gift card redeem it and its very easy.. and your up to buy your Backpack expander..

Answer (score 0):

The backpack expander is not available through crafting, so either you pay money in the store or you find someone to trade it to you.

I do remember when I got mine that it was a rare item for people to have, but not expensive when I finally found a person with it.

If you aren't willing to pay, then all you can do is keep doing what you're doing.